# After Typo3 upgrade, dam fatal errors

Tags: upgrade, typo3-6.2.x, dam, fal

I just upgraded a typo3 4.5 LTS to typo3 6.2 LTS. The process went smoothly, I also updated some extensions to work fine with the new version of typo3. So I could see the backend but not the Frontend. I get Fatal errors related to the "dam" extensions . There are about 4 extensions that are based on dam. I installed "dam_falmigration" and run its commands in the command line as mentioned in its [documentation](https://github.com/b13/t3ext-dam_falmigration/blob/master/Documentation/UserManual/Index.rst)

But nothing has changed , at least the frontend, I keep seeing the same fatal errors. I kept googling for the next step to take after that, but as you may know Typo3 misses a lot when it comes to documentation.

So I am asking here if somebody has been through this just to give me hints and guide me how can I make it work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And did you uninstall DAM and the extensions that relate to it? 
Dam to fal will only migrate data to fal, but not fix dam ext.

Comment: yes I did and then the fatal errors related to dam disappeared , but now I get :  Class 'tx_gridelements_pi1' not found in /home/www/dev2.physikinstrumente.com/typo3_src-6.2.13/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php

Comment: update gridelements.  and all extensions in your repo

Comment: That was the first thing I did, but I just found the solution for it elsewhere.

Comment: it would be nice if you also post your solution for others ;)

Comment: well the solution for the 2nd issue was that I added  <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:gridelements/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.txt"> in Web > Template > constant.txt  and <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:gridelements/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt"> in setup.txt in the same folder

Comment: @thegentletrainer Include the grid element template TS Template .